# Determine the RSA private key from public key

Tags: rsa, public-key, keys

I was told that you can determine the private key of an RSA encryption with the public key.

I thought the point of a public key was to avoid letting people find the private key, but anyway, they said I could find it by simply factoring the public key modulus? Were they joshing me or can it be done? If so, how would I do that (need to acquire $p,q$ somehow?)?

So with with example Public Key $( e, n ) = ( 13, 119 )$ or any other valid key you want to use...

Comment: Note that solving a Sudoku is also considered a *hard* problem, given large enough dimensions of the Sudoku. Hard problems are not *impossible* problems; they are just hard to solve for large enough puzzles.

Answer (score 2):

> I was told that you can determine the private key of an RSA encryption with the public key. Were they joshing me or can it be done?

Yes, it can be done. What you have not been told is that to factor a public key (usually hundreds of digits) to find the private key,  requires a time exponential in the length of the public key, 
therefore even a supercomputer could take years, if not centuries. Factorization is believed to be a ***Hard Problem***.
 On the other hand, if you already know the private key, you can get the plaintext in very few CPU's cicles. 
This is the general principle underlying asymmetric cryptography:

Comment: There are known subexponential (but superpolynomial) factoring algorithms.

Comment: A "second" is a specific amount of time. Maybe you could think of another term? (My brain has trouble to come up with a good synonym, I must admit.) Um, "almost instantly" or" directly" would present themselves.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes what about "in very few CPU cycles"? If 
it fits better, I change the answer.

Comment: @Maeher I know but assuming basic knowledge from the OP I didn't want to complicate things for him.

Comment: They sounded pretty confident it wouldn't take very long then threw $(n = 7354943; e = 7)$ at me, then said use wolfram alpha. What input would wolfram alpha need to do it?

Comment: @Anan Well, in the case of WolframAlpha, you can just enter `n = 7354943` but I'd call that cheating :)

Comment: It just recognizes a known multiplication of two prime numbers and shows it. Because of that it doesn't require context; this is just a property of such a low value number.

Comment: @Anan 7354943 it's a ***RIDICULOUSLY*** small number ... RSA public keys can have 1000+ digits.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes gcd(n,e) is what i was thinking of

Comment: Good. Try it, it's an exercise after all.

Comment: "Factorization is known to be a Hard Problem" now this is just wrong. It is *believed* to be hard. It's absolutely not *known* to be hard.

Comment: @Maeher, you are absolutely right. Sorry, a slip of mine.

Comment: Let's say I have factors of public key, how to find private key then?